# ls - Not working in certain directories

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, directory, ls

Good afternoon, I recently downloaded [this](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/) .bash_profile setup, but I'm running into a small issue when running the `ls` command in Terminal (Mac OS X - Sierra, 10.12.6).

[image: Error 1]

`ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]`

As you can see, I have no aliases, and ls is where it should be (at least I hope).

What's going on here? Anything I should do to try to remedy this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in how `*` works in the shell.

Some people think that when you write `ls *` the shell will run `ls` passing the wildcard and that command will list all the files. But actually it is the shell that *expands* the `*` into a list of all the files and passes them to `ls`.

**TL;DR;** you have a directory name that starts with `-`! (I think that it is named just `-`). So when you run `ls -d */` it is expanded to something like `ls -d -/ bar/ muz/ ...`. You can see the actual expansion with `echo ls -d */`

Solution: write `ls -d -- */`. The `--` will tell the command not to interpret any further command starting with `-` as an option, but as a file name.

Comment: Huh, that's kind of unintuitive, but fascinating nonetheless! Do you know if there's any historical reason this is the case? I'd love to learn more!

Comment: @RicardoIglesias: Unintuitive indeed. Be thankful that you discovered this with `ls`... I did a lot of years ago with `rm`!

Comment: Another solution (for versions of `ls` or other command that don't support `--`) is to use `ls -d ./*/`. The extra `./` in front of the file pattern doesn't affect their interpretation as filenames ("./" just means "in the current directory"), but it does make them unambiguous, since `./-` will not be mistaken for a command option.

Comment: Thank you - StackOverflow saved the world again today! It is really bizarrely unintuitive.